# How to get the body of all of the emails in my inbox and append them into a doc with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to create a program that logs the user's inbox. I got a bit stuck on this. Please help me out!

Comment: In order to correctly understand about `I would like to create a program that logs the user's inbox. I got a bit stuck on this.`, can you provide your current script and explain about the detail of current issue of your script? By the way, about your goal, for example, when the email is HTML body, how output do you want?

Comment: Welcome! Please review [ask] from the intro tour. "Show me how to write the code" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt to find the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getMyEmailsInToAGoogleDoc() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id");
  const doc = DocumentApp.create('myDoc');
  const fileid = doc.getId();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const ts = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  let msgs = '';
  ts.forEach(t => {
    t.getMessages().forEach(m => {
      let msg = Utilities.formatString('To: %s\nFrom: %s\nSubject: %s\nMessage: %s\n--------------------------------------\n', m.getTo(), m.getFrom(), m.getSubject(), m.getPlainBody());
      msgs += msg;
      body.appendParagraph(msg);
    });
  });
  doc.saveAndClose();
  Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": folder.getId()}]},fileid);//Move into desired folder
  Logger.log(msgs);
}
```